# sh read command eats backslashes in input?

Tags: shell, sh, backslash

Perhaps easiest to explain with an example:

```
$ echo '\&|'
\&|
$ echo '\&|' | while read in; do echo "$in"; done
&|
```

It seems that the `read` command is interpreting the backslashes in the input as escapes and is removing them.  I need to process a file line by line without changing its contents and I'm not sure how to stop read from being smart here.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Accrding to: http://www.vias.org/linux-knowhow/bbg_sect_08_02_01.html :

> -r
>   If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character.
>   The backslash is considered to be part
>   of the line. In particular, a
>   backslash-newline pair may not be used
>   as a line continuation.

It works on my machine.

```
$ echo '\&|' | while read -r in; do echo "$in"; done
\&|
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I feel dumb for not having found the documentation for this, but it's one of those things that's hard to search for because the terms are rather generic :(

Comment: Btw, what shell are you using that does not require the -r?  I'm using bash.

Comment: Watch out that this is not exactly true for read on zsh: [documentation of built-in commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html).
Difference: -r just prints '\' if it is at the _end_ of the line. So `read -r in && echo $in` will echo two lines if you enter `foo\nbar`

Comment: @normanius the difference is not in `read`, it's in `echo` - the zsh built in `echo` converts escape sequences like `\n` by default, whereas the bash built in you have to opt in to escape processing with `echo -e`

Answer (score 7):

Use `read -r`, as per http://www.ss64.com/bash/read.html:

> -r
>       If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character.