# While loop is not reading a '\' from a file in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop

I am trying to read a line in a file which has '\' in it. But it is not showing in output, please help me what is the reason behind and how to read it.

Ex: 
File has this data:

```
abc
abc\def
```

but while loop took the second line as 'abcdef'

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Comment: Can "\" sign be a special character?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [-r option](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html). E.g in bash:

```
while read -r l; do 
  echo "$f"; 
done < yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

\ (backslash ) is an escape character .
If possible use abc\\def instead of abc\def

Or use -r in your shell script as mentioned in the SO thread

[sh read command eats slashes in input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924388/sh-read-command-eats-slashes-in-input)

Comment: I have used abc\\def instead of abc\def before. I think using '-r' is comfortable than our assumption. It's working with '-r'. Thank You..