# Replace string '\n' (not 'end of line') in bash script

Tags: windows, string, bash, shell

There is `\n` string in my file.

Contents of the file `source.txt` is only one row with text (plus enter at end of first line):

```
I want to replace only substring \nconsisting of characters \\ and n
```

You can see `\n` substring inside before "consisting" word. I want to replace this substring with substring `\n` and some ident spaces. My script is in file `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ident="         "
rep_old="\n"
rep_new="\n$ident"

FILE=source.txt
while read line
do
  echo -e "$line"
  echo -e "NEW: ${line//$rep_old/$rep_new}"
done < $FILE
```

Actual output after call `script.sh` from bash (my os is Windows):

```
I want to replace only substring nconsisting of characters \ and n
NEW: I wa
         t to replace o
         ly substri
         g
         co
         sisti
         g of characters \ a
         d
```

But I want to replace only one `\n`. I tried also use `rep_old="\\n"` but without success. What is correct way to achieve this two variants of result?

1: `I want to replace only substring \n         consisting of characters \\ and n`

2: `I want to replace only substring 
         consisting of characters \\ and n`

**What I try based to yours answers:**

**A:** `rep_old="\\\\n"`

**A: result:**

```
I want to replace only substring nconsisting of characters \ and n
NEW: I want to replace only substring nconsisting of characters \ and n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with 'double escaping', happening at variable set time AND at use time
consider this:

```
$ echo "\\n"
\n

$ x="\\n"
$ echo $x
\n
```

so even if I escape n with \\ on *creation* on *use* its \n

try:

```
$ rep_old="\\\\n"
```

which gives

```
$ echo $rep_old
\\n
```

**UPDATED**
Sorry you have a second problem, which is:

```
while read line <-- this is already eating the \n as it is reading that as an escape
do
  echo -e "$line"
```

see this:
[sh read command eats slashes in input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924388/sh-read-command-eats-slashes-in-input)

try this:

```
while read -r line
```

giving:

```
I want to replace only substring
consisting of characters \ and n
NEW: I want to replace only substring
         consisting of characters \ and n
```

Comment: Sorry, this not helping me. See my update question with this test - no ident and looks like nothing was replaced.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct solution with double escaping.