# Unable to read backslash in user input before putting it in variable

Tags: bash, shell

```
echo -ne " Enter Username: "
read -r username echo $username
```

User Input: `admin\admin`
Output: `admin^Gdmin`

Any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924388/sh-read-command-eats-slashes-in-input

Comment: Script works for me, did you quote the variable when you output it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read -r` and use quoted variable in `echo`:

```
read -rp "Enter Username: " username
Enter Username: admin\admin
echo "$username"
admin\admin
```

Also `echo -ne` isn't allowed since you can use `read -p`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, echo "$username" works but if I do this, it doesn't work:

echo "$username" > /etc/file.csv
vi files.csv Output: admin^Gdmin

Comment: `echo "$username" > /etc/file.csv` and `vi` works fine for me. What does `cat -vte /etc/file.csv` show to you?

Comment: This is what I see admin^Gdmin$

Comment: I can't reproduce it since I am getting `admin\admin` in terminal and in `vi`

Comment: by the way i used echo -e "\n"$username""

Comment: If I remove -e it worked but then \n doesn't work, any idea why >

Comment: `echo -e "\n"$username""` is wrong. Using `-e` will break it. You can use: `echo $'\n'"$username" > /tmp/file.csv`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, didn't get a chance to test it out,  I am sure this was the issue, Thanks a lot, will update soon